# The improper integral evaluation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I need to evaluate the following integral:
$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\frac{\frac{q}{p}\frac{x^{-p}-1}{x^{-q}-1}-1%
}{x^{-q}-1}dx,$$ where $0<p/2<q\leq p$.
It seems not to have a closed-form solution (except for $q=p$ when $I=0$). However, showing that it is finite (as calculations show) would be also great.
The integrand converges to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, and to $0$ as $x\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: This diverges from some choices of $p,q$, but converges for others.

Comment: It seems to converge for all $0<q\leq p$.

Comment: Diverges when $q=1/3,p=2/3$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems that $p/2<q\leq p$ is needed for divergence. I updated the question.

Comment: Yes, the integrand is $\frac{1}{2x}$ if $q=p/2$. Hence, $I$ diverges.

Comment: Why not prove convergence yourself?

Comment: Do you have a simple (or any other) proof of the convergence? If so, please post it. If not, then why don't you prove it if it is easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the integrand
$$\frac{ qx^q-px^p+(p-q) x^{p+q}} { p\, \left(x^q-1\right)^2 \,x^{p-q+1}}$$ there is an antiderivative which express in term of the Gaussian hypergeometric function.
$$\frac{\left(x^p-1\right) x^{q}}{p\, x^p\left(x^q-1\right)}-\frac{x^{q-p}}{p} \,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{q-p}{q};\frac{2q-p}{q};x^q\right)+$$
$$\frac{\log \left(1-x^q\right)}{q}-\frac{\log
   \left(1-x^q\right)}{p}$$

Using the bounds and simplifying, the definite integral is just
$$\large\color{blue}{I=\frac 1q-\frac{p-q}{p\,q} \,H_{-\frac{p}{q}}}$$ where $H_n$ is the generalized  harmonic number.

Remember that Euler integral representation of harmonic numbers is
$$H_n=\int_0^1 \frac {1-x^n }{1-x }\,dx$$

Looking at the bounds of $q$ and using asymptotics

- If $q=p \left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon \right)$
  $$p\,I=\frac{1}{4 \epsilon }+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2(\pi
     ^2+6)}{3}  \epsilon+4 \left(4 \zeta (3)+\pi ^2+2\right)
     \epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$
- If $q=p \left(1-\epsilon \right)$
  $$p\,I=\epsilon+\frac{\pi^2+6}6\epsilon^2+\left(\zeta (3)+\frac{\pi ^2}{3}+1\right) \epsilon
     ^3+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right)$$

**Edit**

Let $q=\frac 12 p(1+x)$ with $0 < x <1$ and use Wolfram Alpha to plot
$$p\,I=f(x)=\frac{2+(x-1) H_{-\frac{2}{x+1}}}{x+1}$$

Just copy/past the next line.

`Plot[(2+(x-1)*HarmonicNumber[-2/(1+x)])/(1+x),{x,0,1}]`

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, what is $H_{-p/q}$ in your expression?

Comment: Also, if $p=q$, then obviously $I=0$. In your answer, however, $I=1/q$. It does not seem correct.

Comment: @Max. Clarified and completed with asymptotics.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't know much about the generalized harmonic numbers. However, when tried to numerically evaluate $I$ by using your formula with a few values of $(p,q)$ that satisfy the conditions, and the integral representation of $H_{-p/q}$ you provided, then $H(.)$ diverged. Are you sure that your lines are correct?

Comment: "numerically evaluate" means that I just used a math processor with various values of $(p,q)$, and it returned that $H_{-p/q}$ diverged.

Comment: @Max.I had a sign error in the blue formula. Look at the edit. It could be good you add the plot in the post. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Just in case, I don't know how to add plots in posts, so let's leave it as is :)

Answer (score 1):

We know the integrand is continuous on $(0,1]$.  So we must investigate the integrand as $x \to 0^+$.  The OP says the case $q=p$ is already done.  So assume $0 < p/2 < q < p$.

Then as $x \to 0^+$ we have
\begin{align}
x & \to 0
\\
x^{-p} & \to +\infty\qquad\text{since }-p<0
\\
x^{-p} - 1 & \sim x^{-p}
\\
x^{-q} - 1 & \sim x^{-q}\qquad\text{similarly}
\\
\frac{x^{-p} - 1}{x^{-q} - 1} & \sim x^{-p+q}
\\
\frac{q}{p}\frac{x^{-p} - 1}{x^{-q} - 1} & \sim \frac{q}{p}x^{-p+q}
 \to +\infty\quad\text{since }-p+q<0
\\
\frac{q}{p}\frac{x^{-p} - 1}{x^{-q} - 1}-1 & \sim \frac{q}{p}x^{-p+q}
\\
x^{-q}-1 & \sim x^{-q}\qquad\text{already noted above }
\\
\frac{\frac{q}{p}\frac{x^{-p} - 1}{x^{-q} - 1}-1}{x^{-q}-1}
&\sim \frac{q}{p} x^{-p+2q}
\\
\frac{1}{x}\frac{\frac{q}{p}\frac{x^{-p} - 1}{x^{-q} - 1}-1}{x^{-q}-1}
&\sim \frac{q}{p} x^{-p+2q-1}
\end{align}
But $-p+2q-1 > -1$, so
$$
\int_0^1 x^{-p+2q-1}\;dx < + \infty
$$
and by comparison,
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\frac{\frac{q}{p}\frac{x^{-p} - 1}{x^{-q} - 1}-1}{x^{-q}-1}
\;dx < +\infty .
$$

Comment: Thank you. Also, there is indeterminacy $0/0$ in the integrand as $ x\rightarrow 1$, by I can deal with it by L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

Define the harmonic number $H(s)$ by

$$ H(s) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x^s}{1-x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+s} \right). $$

When $s = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, $ we easily check that $H(s) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{s}$. So, the above integral extends the harmonic number for non-integral arguments. Then we prove:

> **Claim.** For $p, q > 0$, OP's integral $I$ converges if and only if $p < 2q$. In this case,
>
> $$ I = \frac{q-p}{qp}\left( H_{1-p/q} - 1 \right). $$

Indeed, let $p, q > 0$. Then with $\alpha = p/q$,

\begin{align*}
I
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{x^{-q}-1}\biggl( \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{x^{-p}-1}{x^{-q}-1}-1 \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{q-1}}{1 - x^q}\biggl( \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{x^{q-p} - x^q}{1 - x^q} - 1 \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{q} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1 - t}\biggl( \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{t^{1-\alpha} - t}{1 - t} - 1 \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}t \tag{$t = x^q$}
\end{align*}

Since the singularity of the integrand at $t = 1$ is removable for any value of $\alpha$, the convergence of $I$ is determined by the singularity of the integrand near $t = 0$. This then shows that the inntegral $I$ converges if and only if $\alpha < 2$, or equivalently, $p < 2q$.

To evaluate the last integral, we consider the corresponding indefinite integral. Perform integration by parts and using $\left( \frac{t}{1-t} \right)' = \frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$, we get

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{1 - t}\biggl( \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{t^{1-\alpha} - t}{1 - t} - 1 \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}t
&= \frac{1}{\alpha} \int \frac{t^{1-\alpha} - t}{(1 - t)^2} \, \mathrm{d}t
- \int \frac{1}{1 - t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{t(t^{1-\alpha} - t)}{1 - t}
- \int \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{t((1-\alpha)t^{-\alpha} - 1)}{1 - t} \, \mathrm{d}t
- \int \frac{1}{1 - t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{t^{2-\alpha} - t^2}{1 - t}
+ \frac{1}{\alpha} \int \frac{(1-\alpha)(1-t^{1-\alpha}) - (1 - t)}{1 - t} \, \mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

So, if $\alpha < 2$, then

\begin{align*}
I
&= \lim_{\substack{a \to 0^+ \\ b \to 1^-}} \frac{1}{q} \biggl( \biggl[ \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{t^{2-\alpha} - t^2}{1 - t} \biggr]_{a}^{b}
+ \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{(1-\alpha)(1-t^{1-\alpha}) - (1 - t)}{1 - t} \, \mathrm{d}t \biggr) \\
&= \frac{1}{q} \biggl( 1 + \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha} H_{1-\alpha} - \frac{1}{\alpha} \biggr) \\
&= \frac{q-p}{qp}\left( H_{1-p/q} - 1 \right)
\end{align*}

as required. $\square$

Comment: Thank you, well done :)

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^1 x^{2q-p-1}\frac{(p-q)x^p-px^{p-q}+q}{p(1-x^q)^2}dx$$
By $x=u^{1/q}$ substitution
$$I=\frac1{pq}\int_0^1\frac{(p-q)u-p+qu^{1-\frac pq}}{(1-u)^2}du$$
After integration by parts
$$I=\frac1q-\frac{p-q}{pq}\int_0^1\frac{1-u^{-\frac pq}}{1-u}du\\=\frac1q-\frac{p-q}{pq}H_{-\frac pq}$$
for $p<2q$.

Comment: I think you forgot some multipliers in the last expression.